# Fingerprint Authentication Login Page Touch Id / Client Id Ionic Android/IOS

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic3

I'm new on Ionic 3. I try to use fingerprint on Login page.On sign up user will put fingerprint as an option, what  parameters should i send to backend? I try to find something like fingerprint model (biometric fingerprint), and every time on login to check the current model fingerprint with model from backend, but without any luck. On ionic  i found plugin fingerprintAio, I use this plugin to initiate fingerprint authentication, I check fingerprint using fingerprint scanner on my phone,  but it send a client Id (I don't know where I can find or generate, and after sign up, on login I don't know how to take that client ID).

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

SIGN UP:

```
   async fingerprintFunction(){
   try{
  await this.platform.ready();
  const keyTest = await this.fingerPrintAIO.isAvailable()
  let fingerOption= {
    clientId: this.device.uuid     // I try to use device.uuid
    clientSecret: 'password',
    disableBackup:true,
  }
 if(keyTest){
  this.fingerPrintAIO.show(fingerOption)
        .then((result: any) => {              
         console.log(result)
        })
     .catch((error: any) =>
         console.log(error));


  }
}
catch(error){
  console.log(error)
}
}
```

LOGIN:

```
  async openFingerprintDialog(){
      try{
    await this.platform.ready();
    await this.androidFingerprintAuth.isAvailable()
                .then((result)=> {
                  if(result.isAvailable){                        

                    this.androidFingerprintAuth.encrypt({ clientId: this.device.uuid})
                      .then(result => {
                        console.log("Result", result)

                        if (result.withFingerprint) {
                            console.log('Successfully encrypted credentials.');
                            console.log('Encrypted credentials: ' + result.token);
                        } else if (result.withBackup) {
                          console.log('Successfully authenticated with backup password!');
                        } else console.log('Didn\'t authenticate!');
                      })
                      .catch(error => {
                        if (error === this.androidFingerprintAuth.ERRORS.FINGERPRINT_CANCELLED) {
                          console.log('Fingerprint authentication cancelled');
                        } else console.error(error)
                      });

                  } else {
                    console.log("fingerprint auth isn't available");
                  }
                })
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log(e);
    }
```

}